# Cannot use "from" in .numberformat vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have 2 cells where user is entering values, placed next to each other like:
`200` `1200`
Using .numberformat i want to change it to
`From 200` `To 1200`
I can use any other word but "from" is giving me an `Run-time error 1004`
Code I wanted to use:
`Range("B42:B44").NumberFormat = ("From" & "##0.0\°F")
Range("C42:C44").NumberFormat = ("To " & "##0.0\°F")`
Any ideas how can I bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test in a number format should be enclosed in quotes:

```
Range("B42:B44").NumberFormat = """From""##0.0""°F"""
```

or you can escape each character with `\` as you did with the degree symbol, but that gets tedious!

Comment: `Range("B42:B44").NumberFormat = ("""From""##0.0""°F""")`   You forgot to place bracket at the beggining but works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Agreed but for a short word like From I prefer the escape characters as using the right number of nested quotes is more tedious. :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a VBA problem. If you right click the cell and goto format/custom and type From ##0.0\°F you get an error. But regardless, you can fix it either manually or in VBA by escaping out the problem characters:

```
Range("B42:B44").NumberFormat = ("F\ro\m ##0.0°F")
```

Comment: I have changable temperature units from °F to °C on my sheet so I cannot set it permanently, need to adjust to user's preferences

Comment: I figured, that's why I posted the VBA code and not just the manual instructions. Was just letting you know that it was less a VBA syntax issue and more of excel in general. With odd stuff like this I always remove as many variables as possible, so the first thing I did was try it manually. That didn't work, so then focus on getting it working there before getting it working in the script. Once one was solved, the other was also.